# mongotranslate and schema aggregation in mongo connector for bi

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api, mongodb-connector-for-bi

Im a BI analyst, new to mongodb. Currently using Mongo Connector For Bi in order to connect my MongoDB to Tableau. 
Im trying to learn how SQL queries can be expressed in the MongoDB aggregation language by using 'mongotranslate' command, but it seems the CMD can't find this function. 
What i have tried:

```
mongotranslate “select * from groceries.fruits where _id >100;”\ --schema schema.drdl
```

Then i got:

```
mongotranslate is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Is someone here familiar with mongodrdl? i'd appreciate the help

Comment: What is the version of MongoDB you have in your system?

Comment: My MongoDB version is 3.2.7

Comment: Quick question, Are you calling the mongotranslate command from the system folder where you have installed mongodb or outside folder. Make sure mongod --help command is working

Comment: I need to activate it from the MongoDB folder? not the Mongo connector for BI folder?

Comment: Wherever the application .exe available. If the application is not in PATH variable we cannot access from outside. Perhaps you can check " https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/" for add application to PATH variable.

Comment: Would the mongotranslate exe be in MongoDB path or the connector path?